# Keyboard Long Key Press in Android WebVIew

Tags: javascript, android, webview, event-handling, keydown

Anyone have any ideas how to handle a long press of a keyboard key in Android WebView. I had assumed I would simply be able to use the **KeyboardEvent** ***repeat*** property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) but when I tested it with the following code, the repeat property returned is always false, despite holding a key down.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(event) {
    console.log(event.repeat);
}
```

The above code works as expected on a desktop browser and returns false once, then true repeatedly, while a key is held down. However in Android WebView, it repeatedly returns false.

Any ideas what the issue is, or an alternative way to handle a long keyboard key press?

**Update**
To clarify, I'm trying to bind to the long press key event rather than ignore it. I want to trigger a function if a key is held down for a duration of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the document.onkeydown function, then process the corresponding key value through the anti jitter mechanism. After all, what we need to deal with is the key value, not the long key. The code as follows:

```
var throttle = function(func, delay) {
            var prev = Date.now();
            return function() {
                var context = this;
                var args = arguments;
                var now = Date.now();
                if (now - prev >= delay) {
                    func.apply(context, args);
                    prev = Date.now();
                }
            }
        }
function onkeypress(evt) {
    var keycode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    console.log(keycode);
}

document.onkeypress = throttle(onkeypress, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate on what you mean regarding using the "anti jitter mechanism"? For example, how would I go about listening for a long press on the Enter key?

Comment: On the Android, a long keys means that a lot of key events are reported in a period of time, but you only need to process it once within a specified time.

Comment: Thanks again for replying but unless I'm mistaken, this won't work as intended. Using this code, if I press the Enter Key once then simply wait for longer than the half second delay and press it again, the function is triggered. 

I want the opposite behavior where the function only triggers if you hold down the enter key for a specified amount of time.

Comment: You could reduce the time of the throttle function , such as: document.onkeypress = throttle(onkeypress, 150);

Comment: Oops, maybe you should handle the onkeyup function.

Comment: I'd investigated using 'onkeyup' but that would mean I could only capture the "long press" after the user releases the key. i.e. the key could be held down for 60 seconds without the 'long press event' firing