# Keyboard Long Key Press in Android WebVIew

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, webview, javascript

Anyone have any ideas how to handle a long press of a keyboard key in Android WebView. I had assumed I would simply be able to use the **KeyboardEvent** ***repeat*** property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) but when I tested it with the following code, the repeat property returned is always false, despite holding a key down.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(event) {
    console.log(event.repeat);
}
```

The above code works as expected on a desktop browser and returns false once, then true repeatedly, while a key is held down. However in Android WebView, it repeatedly returns false.

Any ideas what the issue is, or an alternative way to handle a long keyboard key press?

**Update**
To clarify, I'm trying to bind to the long press key event rather than ignore it. I want to trigger a function if a key is held down for a duration of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard Long Key Press in Android WebVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433396/keyboard-long-key-press-in-android-webview)

Comment: (the OP posted the same question using different accounts but same name)